# Multimap no match for operator==

Tags: c++, c++11, multimap

I have this `multimap` inside a `Bar class`, with an `unsigned long` and a reference to the `Foo class`.

```
class Bar
{
//etc.
        struct map_sort
        {
            bool operator()(const unsigned long& e1, const unsigned long& e2) const
            {
                return (e2 < e1);
            }
        };

    std::multimap<const unsigned long,const Foo&, map_sort> m_map;

    find_and_erase(const unsigned long var1, const Foo& var2);
}
```

And now I want to retrieve all the values from the multimap and erase some.

```
void Bar::find_and_erase(const unsigned long var1, const Foo& var2)
{
    auto it = m_map.begin();

    for (it=m_map.begin(); it!=m_map.end(); ++it)
    {
        const unsigned long first = (*it).first;
        const Foo& second = (*it).second;
        if((first == var1) && (second == var2)) //<----ERROR No Match for operator==
            m_map.erase(it);
    }
}
```

**Question**

How can I compare the `(second == var2)` ?

(What I want is to find all entries from a multimap, and delete the ones on the `find_and_erase()` function, that matches the function argument. Don't know if there is an easier solution for this)

Comment: Implement `operator==` for `Foo`?

Comment: You are trying to compare two `Foo`s for equality.  No map of any kind has anything to do with it. Besides, you are not using the multimap right. You have a key at hand, and then go ahead and perform a linear search for that key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the equality function for `Foo`s:

```
bool operator==(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    // return whether Foos are equal
}
```

If you define that one, you'll also want to define `!=` for completeness:

```
bool operator=!(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) { return !operator==(a,b); }
```

Also, as per [n.m.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567283/multimap-no-match-for-operator/31568559#comment51092233_31567283), given that you have a `multimap` you should take advantage of it:

```
void Bar::find_and_erase(const unsigned long var1, const Foo& var2)
{
    auto its = m_map.equal_range(var1);
    for (auto it = its.first; it != its.second; ++it) {
        if (it.second == var2) {
            m_map.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```